# Embed HTML Link in Android Button

Tags: android, html

Is it possible to embed a HTML Link in a Button?

I have this advertisement resource:

```
<a href="https://www.financeads.net/tc.php?t=29425C87039197T" target="_blank">Hier klicken</a><img src="https://www.financeads.net/tb.php?t=29425V87039197T" alt="" border="0" width="0" height="0">
```

The affiliate network told me that I have to use the HTML Link and can't just use the url.
I want to show a button in android. When you click the button the url should be open. Is there a possibility to embed this HTML in a Android button?

Comment: you can render button into webview or add button onclick listener for open url using intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the point of embedding an html link in a button? I would override the click on the button by doing:

```
final Button button = findViewById(R.id.button_id);
         button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
                 // Code here executes on main thread after user presses button
                  String url = "https://www.financeads.net/tc.php?t=29425C87039197T";
                  Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                  i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
                  startActivity(i);
             }
         });
```

This way you'll navigate to the link you provided from the browser phone

Answer (score 0):

You can try `setMovementMethod` approach

```
Button btn_text;



btn_text = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_text);

Spanned html = Html.fromHtml("<a href=\"https://www.financeads.net/tc.php?t=29425C87039197T\" target=\"_blank\">Hier klicken</a><img src=\"https://www.financeads.net/tb.php?t=29425V87039197T\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\" width=\"0\" height=\"0\">");

    /*
    setMovementMethod(MovementMethod movement)
    Sets the movement method (arrow key handler) to be used for this Button.

    LinkMovementMethod
    A movement method that traverses links in the text buffer and
    scrolls if necessary. Supports clicking on links with
    DPad Center or Enter.
    */
btn_text.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());

// Set Button text from html
btn_text.setText(html);
```

Imp : make sure you have set Internet permission in android manifest file

Comment: I dont want to show the html. But I have to use the html. I only want to show a button